# Redstone trouble

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

How do I place redstone dust on a dispenser? I am making a combat world and I want to make a TNT cannon. I tried tapping on the top of the dispenser, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

**On PC:**

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> (or if you changed key bindings, the sneak key) while placing to be able to place redstone on blocks that you can interact with (furnace, crafting table, dispenser etc.).

**On Pocket Edition:**

Press the sneak button, it should look like this (it should be a dark circle with a light circle in it):

[image: Position of crouch button on screen]

and not like this (it shouldn't be a dark circle only):

[image: Not the jump button]

**On console editions:**

Press the right analog stick (until it clicks, down on D Pad on PS Vita) to toggle the Sneak mode.

[image: Right Analog Stick on Xbox One Controller] [image: Right Analog Stick on Dualshock 4 Controller] [image: Right Analog Stick on Playstation Vita]

Comment: What about Xbox and PlayStation?

Comment: @JimJones here you go